# Arduino + JohnnyFive - How to send a .JS file to Arduino using only HTML and a web interface

Tags: javascript, terminal, arduino, johnny-five, firmata

I'm new to programming and have a basic understanding of JavaScript and HTML.

I have set up an Arduino which has StandardFirmata on it and works with JohnnyFive and Socket io to create a web interface that can control LED's and turn them on and off separately using buttons. At the moment I have to use Terminal to direct to the folder that contains the JS file and run 'node_.JS' for the Arduino and web interface to start working.

Is there a way to do this without sending commands via the terminal and for it to run the JS file by something on the web interface? I would like to only have the web interface and Arduino used as this is aimed for children.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to wrap you web app and node app in single "file" for easy use. Try [Nwjs](http://nwjs.io/).